# What should I switch my cpu to?

Tags: processor, server, upgrade

I'm running my old computer from like 6 or 7 years ago as a server, and for the most part it works fine. I have some extra money, and when it is bottlenecked, the cpu causes the bottleneck. The current cpu is an AMD Athlon X4 860k, and the motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-F2A68HM-H, and I would like to upgrade the cpu. Is there a good cpu that is compatible with the motherboard that I can purchase for under $200?

Comment: It has an FM2+ socket. However, [this source](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket_FM2_.html) says that there is no significantly better CPU for FM2+. Probably you need to upgrade also your motherboard. If you do that, you will likely want to avoid to replace also the memory.

Comment: @peterh If I'm going to replace the motherboard, I'm just going to put together a whole new system. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can not significantly upgrade the CPU, because there is no significant better CPU. A motherboard replacement does not mean a whole system replacement, it is typically not more costly than the CPU, although it is more work to replace.

Comment: Btw, I think it is far more likely that the RAM is the real bottleneck. That motherboard can handle 64GB max.

Comment: I don't think the ram is the bottleneck, server ram usage is only 500-1000mb. The computer is 6-7 years old, and I feel like it would be better to put together one specifically   for running servers. If you have a suggestion for a new board and cpu that has DDR3 ram slots, that would be very useful as well.

Comment: So you want the highest CPU (maybe IO) performance from $200 with a DDR3 compatible cpu + motherboard combo. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I think there is nothing from $200 what you could buy and would be significantly better. I think you could roughly double the performance for about $500. At this point, DDR3 becomes bottleneck. But I did not check the prices very deeply, and you might find some exceptional offer.